# Login-form validation for Play! 2.0

Tags: forms, authentication, playframework, form-authentication

```
public static Result authenticate() {
    Form<LoginForm> loginForm = form(LoginForm.class).bindFromRequest();

    if (loginForm.hasErrors()) {
        return ok(views.html.Account.index.render(loginForm));
    } else {
            String email = loginForm.get().email;
            User user = User.findByUsername(email);

            if (Hash.checkPassword(loginForm.get().password, user.passwordHash)) {
                // set session
                session("email", email);
                return redirect(routes.UserController.view(user.getId()));
            } else {
                return badRequest(views.html.Account.index.render(loginForm));
            }
        }
}
```

We use this code to authenticate users, but we'd like to display error-messages when something goes amiss during login (invalid username / password etc.). However, we can't really find any documentation on this online - as most of the documentation surrounding the use of flash for error messages is mostly for Play 1.x.

1) How can we add error messages to this log in functionality?

2) How can we access these error messages in the view?

3) How (in general) does the form class in Play! handle the creation and handling of errors (and how can we access them?)

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@1) Normally you add errors via Validation. So your LoginForm should have a validate-method

@2) form.errors() or fomr.error("Field") and form.globalErrors()

@3) At the binding the errors will created and put into the constructor of the form. How ever form.errors().put(key, error) should work, because the Map isn't copied. But this is more a hack and can be changed in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! We use @Constraints.Required to validate the fields, and this generates the desired errors. The only way we've found to access these errors is through the helper FieldElements.errors, or through the actual Map itself - which is really cumbersome.

Comment: If you use the normal scala-tenplate-helper they print the error for you, see the form-sample. So it's normally easy and you don't must do anything, just use the helper.

Comment: But we want to print out the errors as a group in a box above the fields, and not within the fields as they do in the example. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Just print them by iterating over `form.errors()` and don't use the form-helper.

Comment: The problem with that is that the error messages won't be parsed through the i18n-translator for built-in validation (such as @Constraints.Required will print out error.required instead of "This is Required" etc.). I solved it by adding a hack in the controller though, but i'd like to have a smoother way of doing it.

Comment: Are you sure that `Messages.get(error.key(), error.arguments())` don't  work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `form.withError("name", "Error")`
there is also `form.withGlobalError("Error")`